# value defined in "if-else structure" is not found outside the "if-else structure"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the following code, I expected the compiler to identify that the `output` gets defined either in the `if` section or in the `else` section.

```
val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, 10),
  (2, 20)
)).toDF("A", "B")

val df2 = spark.emptyDataFrame

if(df2.isEmpty){
    val output = df1
}
else{
    val output = df2
}

println(output.show)
```

However, it gives me an error saying  `error: not found: value output`. if I do the same exact implementation in python it works fine and I get the expected output. In order to make this work in spark using scala I have defined `output` as a mutable variable and update it inside the `if-else`.

```
var output = spark.emptyDataFrame

if(df2.isEmpty){
    output = df1
}
else{
    output = df2
}

println(output.show)
```

Why doesn't the first implementation work and is there a way to get the expected outcome without using a mutable variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you come from a **Python** *background* where this kind of behavior is allowed.
In **Scala** this is not possible to achieve as is, because the `if / else` structure creates a new block, and what is defined in a block only resides in such block.
You may fix this by using a mutable variable...

```
var output: DataFrame = _
if(df2.isEmpty){
  output = df1
}
else{
  output = df2
}
```

However, this is very **Java** and goes against the *immutable* principle.
In **Scala**, a block is an expression, and as such, they can return values.
Thus, this is the more idiomatic way to solve the problem in **Scala**.

```
val output = if(df2.isEmpty) df1 else df2
```

Comment: Great explanation. This is exactly what I wanted to know